# std::set constructor signature confusion

Tags: c++

I am reading *C++ Primer* about how to define a `set`. As I look through *cppreference* about `set`, I feel confused about the class and constructor signature of `set`.

From the text:

```
bool compareIsbn(){....}
multiset<Sales_data, decltype(compareIsbn) *> bookstore(compareIsbn)
```

**Text1:**

> To use our own operation, we must define the multiset with two types:
>   the key type, `Sales_data`, and the comparison type, which is a function
>   pointer type that can point to `compareIsbn`.  When we define objects of
>   this type, we supply a pointer to the operation we intend to use. In
>   this case, we supply a pointer to `compareIsbn`:

So from text1, it seems that I need to put a *function pointer* in `set<Class A, a function pointer>`.

But when I look up [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), the "signature"(not sure if it's the right word) is:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

**Question1**: So the second parameter should be a `class`?

---

**Text2:**

> We can write `compareIsbn` instead of `&compareIsbn` as the constructor
>   argument because when we use the name of a function, it is
>   automatically converted into a pointer if needed. We could have
>   written `&compareIsbn` with the same effect.

Also from [cppreference *constructor of set*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set)(I think the textbook is using the first constructor):

```
set();
explicit set( const Compare& comp, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

**Question2**: Doesn't the constructor require a *function reference*? From where it 's saying that it needs a *function pointer*?

---

Need some help to understand the "signature" , thanks in advance :D.

PS:

1. the textbook uses `multiset` as an example, but the "signature" of `set` and `multiset` are quite similar.
2. I don't know what `const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()` means, but I think maybe it's something get done automatically? I may ignore it for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly confused but fairly close to correct.

Type template parameters being specified with 'class' is a historical/syntactical quirk; that actually indicates that parameter is a type. 'typename' is also legal and is semantically identical:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T thing;
}

template<class T>
struct Bar {
    T thing;
}

// Foo and Bar will work identically
```

In the book's example, the type being passed to the template is "pointer to the type of CompareIsbn"

---

As for your second question, remember that `Compare` is a type:

```
template<typename T>
void Foo(const T& object) { ... }
```

The template function Foo expects to be passed a const reference to T. If T is a pointer type, then it expects a const reference to a pointer:

```
Thing* bar = new Thing();
Foo<Thing*>(bar); // This instantiation of the template has signature void (const Thing*&)
```

In the book's example, `Compare` is `decltype(CompareIsbn)*`, so you must pass `const decltype(CompareIsbn)*&` to the constructor.

---

cppreference has a [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) detailing the requirements of the type used for the `Compare` parameter in the `set` template, which you might find useful. The short version is that it just has to be a type such that this code works:

```
// Given Compare comp
// Given Key a, b
bool b = comp(a, b);
```

There are then some requirements on how that call to `operator()` must behave.

A function pointer will work in that context, so it's fine. But so would `std::function`, or any type that implements `operator()` with the right behaviour. The `= std::less<Key>` bit in the template declaration is setting the default value for the `Compare` parameter to be such an object, which just attempts to use `Key::operator<`.

The `Allocator` parameter is also a function-like object that is used to create new `Key` objects when necessary. You very rarely have to provide an explicit allocator; the default implementation will work fine in almost all cases.

Comment: Thank you :D. I will come back after I learn Template section.

Answer (score 1):

> So from text1, it seems that I need to put a function pointer in `set<Class A, a function pointer>`

Not quite. Yes you need to provide a function pointer to the constructor, but the text tells you that you need to provide a **type** as an argument to the template. Said type needs to be the type of a function pointer.

> So the second parameter should be a class?

The second parameter needs to be a type. Template type parameters are designated by one of two keyword, either `class` or `typename`. But they mean the same thing, the argument you provide must be a type.

> Doesn't the constructor require a function reference?

No, it requires a reference to an object of the type you gave as an argument. Since you give a function pointer as the type, it needs a reference to a function pointer. That's what it ultimately receives.